# Python to check if a time (HH:mm:ss) is present within two columns values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, between

I Have a dataframe(df1) which has the time values in `HH:MM:SS` format .

df1

```
 col_a  | col_b  | col_c  | col_d

00:00:15|00:01:15|00:01:30|00:02:30

00:02:45|00:04:00|00:05:30|00:06:30
```

I have a value stored in a variable `check_time="00:01:00"` I need to check if the value is within the range of two column.

As the `check_time` is  between `col_a` and `col_b`  if its present then i would need the below output.

I tried `df1.loc[((df1['Col_a']>check_time) & (df1['Col_b']<=check_time))]` but i am not getting the desired output .

Output:

```
Col_b

00:01:15
```

Comment: Is that the desired output or is it the unwanted output?

Comment: Its the desired output

Answer (score 1):

If by range you mean the time difference between Col_a and Col_b then you need to find first the diff, so something like this:

```
import datetime as dt
start_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(df1['Col_a'], '%H:%M:%S')
end_dt = dt.datetime.strptime(df1['Col_b'], '%H:%M:%S')
diff = (end_dt - start_dt) 
check_time ="00:01:00"
check_time_dt=dt.datetime.strptime(check_time, '%H:%M:%S')
if check_time_dt/60 <= diff/60:
    <do something>
```

Comment: No , Not the time difference . I want to check if the check_time values id between col A and col B if yes then i need to return column B value at that particular where the criteria matched

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to compare time values you will have to convert your string representation into a datetime object. You can use datetime's class strptime() method.

```
from datetime import datetime
check_time_obj = datetime.strptime(check_time, '%H:%M:%S')
```

After which you can handle your comparisons like so:

```
datetime.strptime(df1['Col_a'], '%H:%M:%S') < check_time_obj
```

Comment: I am comparing with datetime object